# Outputing to console results from xlsx file on VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I am writing a piece of code whereby I want the following to happen:

1. the application takes an Excel `.xlsx` file as input
2. the application takes *only* the information you specify and outputs them row by row onto the console

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub FindValueInExcel()
    Using reader As New StreamReader("D:\excelFileTest.csv")
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim readLine As String
            For Each readLine In line
                If readLine = "14" Then
                    Console.WriteLine(readLine)
                End If
            Next

        End While
    End Using

End Sub
```

The problem is the above does not display anything. The code I want it to *just* look at a specific column display all the rows that are 14 and any information on that row based on that column.

Comment: What do you mean by _all the rows that are 14_? Do you want to display any line that contains 14 in it? If so, try changing `If readLine = "14" Then` to `If line.Contains("14") Then`.

Comment: You should be writing `line` to your console, that is the actual line of text from your file. Currently, `readLine` will not have a value. `line` is a string, not an array/collection...so `line` is never going to hold the value `14`

Comment: corrected spelling, removed noise

Comment: Thanks! I got this working and thank you for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is 2-part, one is that you aren't checking the csv line variable's contents correctly, and two you are looking for an entire line to be equal to "14", and if this csv file has anything more than a single column of data you'll never get a line that equals 14. So if you actually check the `line` variable for your value instead of `readLine` (which you don't need) and also use Arun Kumar's suggestion of using `Contains` to search the entire string line for your value, your code would look something like this:

```
Private Sub FindValueInExcel(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal SearchValue As String)
    Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FilePath)
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            If line.Contains(SearchValue) Then
                Console.WriteLine(line)
            End If
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

Called using `FindValueInExcel("D:\excelFileTest.csv", "14")`